# Store view and admin view show different tax for a product

Tags: tax, vat, magento-community

We have one product with 10% vat in our store. In the admin view the tax is calculated and displayed correctly. But the store view shows the product with 24% vat.

Would anyone have any ideas on what might cause the problem?

Comment: Also check both customer country .there is one more possibility country wise text different.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out your settings on the website/store level in system configurations (taxes) and in product taxes. Check out product tax classes etc...

Also you may try to rollback your last changes to check out the difference.